# Synchronization Issue for a Queue

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, queue

I have the following piece of code to access a c++ queue (responseQueue) and send a response after doing some processing:

```
void sendRelpyToClient(){    
    if (responseQueue.empty())
       return;

    static int count = 0;
    Result result;

    SYNCHRONIZE() { //start of synchronization (pseudo-code)

       result = responseQueue.front();
       responseQueue.pop();

    } //end of synchronization

    if(count++ % 9 == 0)
    {
        //simulate some processing with a sleep
        sleep for 15 seconds

    }

    result.sendResult();
}
```

The `responseQueue` contain instances of `Result`. The `sendResult()` method might take some processing time so that for some results that are stored in the queue, it might take relatively longer time for the method to return. The method `sendRelpyToClient()` is accessed by multiple threads, and if `result.sendResult()` is also in the `SYNCHRONIZED()` block, any other thread coming in can be blocked due to a `sendResult()` method which is taking a long time to return. This is the reason why I have chosen this approach.

My logic for this implementation is any thread accessing the responseQueue will first check is the queue is empty and return. since any thread accessing the `SYNCHRONIZE()` block will make the queue empty if there is only one item in it, there is no need to put this check inside the `SYNCHRONIZE()` block. If one thread who is accessing the queue is taken off (by the thread scheduler) right after the `SYNCHRONIZE()` block, the second thread again will take the next item in the queue and call `result.sendResult()`, and when the first thread resumes again it will continue to call `result.sendResult()` with the thread-local value of result (which that thread got from the queue before getiing blocked). The static count variable is there so that I can to simulate long processing for random threads using sleep, since as I've explained above `sendResult()` can take long time for some calls.

I ran a set of tests with this code, so far it has been doing ok. But I just wanted to ask the question here so that I can get your all's ideas about this, if there is any issue with this approach. I'm not an expert on concurrent programming. And if there is a much better, efficient, clean ways to do it, maybe with concurrency not at the queue level but at individual data items' level, please let me know those as well.

Comment: There's a very good reason to push the `empty()` check into the synchronized block. Situation: One item in queue, two threads enter `sendClientReply`. Both pass the `empty()` check and one enters the synchronized block, empties the queue, and moves on. Now when the second thread enters the block, you get undefined behaviour by calling `.front()` on an empty queue.

Comment: I see. +1 for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general your approach is correct, but I want to note 2 things:

1. As was already proposed by Xeo, you should check if queue is empty within synchronized block.
2. You have static variable `count` that is global variable and you read/write it from several threads without synchronization. This is not that dangerous, but may lead to incorrect work of the algorithm. Remember that increment is not atomic operation. You might get situation when 2 threads simultaneously write a new value for count.

UPD:
The fix is  simple:

```
    void sendRelpyToClient(){    
        static int count = 0;
        Result result;

        bool execute = false;

        SYNCHRONIZE() { //start of synchronization (pseudo-code)
            if (responseQueue.empty())
               return;
           result = responseQueue.front();
           responseQueue.pop();

           execute = (count++ % 9 == 0);
        } //end of synchronization

        if (execute)
        {
            //simulate some processing with a sleep
            sleep for 15 seconds
        }
        result.sendResult();
    }
```

Comment: +1. Yes, in this case it doesn't seem to have an issue, but generally for thread safety, I totally agree with your point.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it really thread-safe. Yes, it's not a major issue, but it might happen that 2 threads will sleep at the same time, when just one should.